# Functions With Unlimited Arguments in php

Tags: php, function

I just want to make a function like `array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )`
or simple function like `myfunc($st1, $st2, $st3, $st4, $st5, etc)`

```
function make_my_merge($) {
     ..... operation to be performed ......
}
```

Comment: The number of arguments is limited in PHP (just noting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to access all arguments (as an array) passed to the function. Additionally, you can use [`func_num_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to get a count of all arguments passed in.

```
function make_my_merge () {
    if ( func_num_args() ) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        echo join( ", ", $args );
    }
}

// Foo, Bar
make_my_merge("Foo", "Bar");

// Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz
make_my_merge("Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Buzz");
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/Dk7MD18I

Comment: But what can i do if the arguments are array feeds. i need each element of each array.

Comment: @AbdusSamad If the argument is an array, you can treat it as such and do a `foreach` on it. For instance, if the first argument was an array, with the code above you would do `foreach ( $args[0] as $item )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`func_get_args()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function make_my_merge() {
  $args = func_get_args();

  foreach ($args as $arg) {
    echo "Arg: $arg\n";
  }

}
```

As can be seen, you get all arguments passed to your function via `func_get_args()` function which returns an array you can iterate over using `each` to work on each argument passed.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [PHP Function Variable Arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Answer (score 0):

You would never know how many arguments you want... So you cannot define exact function with unlimited arguments in my opimion. But what I suggest is passing 2 arguments in a function, one as number of index or values in array and other the array itself.... It goes something like this

```
<?php
$arr = array('val1','val2','val3',.....);
$count = count($arr);
$result = your_function($count,$arr);
?>
```

Your function would look like this which goes somewhere on the top or other php files or class

```
<?php
function your_function($count,$arr)
{
   //Here you know the number of values you have in array as $count
   //So you can use for loop or others to merge or for other operations
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
          //Some operation
   }
}
?>
```